# How can I use regex to determine the existence and size of groups of files in C/C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, regex, linux

I have a program on a Linux system that generates data log files with predictable file names that I need to access, but I have to do so through a C/C++ interface. The program accessing the data needs to be able to take a file path with a regex to specify certain file name ranges and do the following:

- Determine if there are files matching the regex that exist
- Determine the total size of all of the matching files

I'm using these as checks before I compress and transfer the files. How can I do this in C/C++?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? This is my email if you want help iharob@gmail.com because as it is no one will give you an answer here. This site is not a code writing service but a help site. If you have a specific problem with your code you can ask here. Otherwise, if you have no clue how to start you can ask me privately if you like.

Comment: Use [std::experimental::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path) Present in `GCC` right now soon to be included in `C++17`.

Comment: What is that language C/C++? There are only the two **different** languages C and C++. You should first pick which one you intend to use.

Comment: Now that there is soon to be a standard filesystem `API` I don't think this question is too broad anymore. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

// make using it sane
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // default to current directory
    fs::path dir = argv[1] ? argv[1] : ".";

    fs::directory_iterator dir_ent{dir};
    fs::directory_iterator dir_end;

    std::regex e{R"~(.*\.txt)~"};
    std::smatch m;

    decltype(fs::file_size("")) total_size = 0;

    for(; dir_ent != dir_end; ++dir_ent)
    {
        // for some reason regex_match won't accept temporaries
        std::string s = dir_ent->path().string();

        if(!std::regex_match(s, m, e))
            continue;

        // deal with filepath here
        total_size += fs::file_size(dir_ent->path());

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about experimental filesystem

Comment: @AlexSt.Clair The "experimental" part is about whether or not it was ready for inclusion in the upcoming standard, it is not a reflection of the quality of the code. :)