# Iterate directory or files with wildcards in c++

Tags: c++

I tried `std::experimental::directory_iterator` but wildcards like `*` and `?` are not suppported.

Are there other way to do this in std library? I shouldn't use 3rd party library.
The program is for windows desktop but it might be ported to mobile devices.

Comment: in what way should be wildcards supported? `directory_iterator` lets you iterate all elements in one directory, I dont see where this could support wildcards. Its not really clear what you actually want to do

Comment: Maybe take the output from `directory_iterator` and push it through `std::regex` code of your own?

Comment: Wildcards are not portable (they behave very differently in different operating systems) so they are not supported in the filesystem library. If you need wildcards as supported by your favourite OS you need to implement them yourself.

Comment: May be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132648/how-can-i-use-regex-to-determine-the-existence-and-size-of-groups-of-files-in-c also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35428586/3807729

Comment: @NeilGatenby yes, that is my top option, but I want to know first if there is already a built in api or class or approach, etc that I can use in std library. Regex seems to much, I only need the functionality that can be done using only the wildcards. But if there's really no built-in alternative, I'll go with regex.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the tip! :) So using the wildcard format is not recommended?

Comment: In addition to why I avoid regex for now is, I have a list of paths the can have wildcards, it can be a very long list. so doing directory iteration and regex(or my own limited pattern matching) on each item given by directory iterator will be 2 loops. I guess I can with go with that but I hope first if there's already available tool that is not 3rd party to achieve my target.